# How to divide in Panda Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I generated the following code:

```
cov_vac_merge['Partially Vaccinated'] = cov_vac_merge['First Dose'] - cov_vac_merge['Second Dose']

cov_vac_merge['% Partially Vaccinated'] = cov_vac_merge['Second Dose'] / cov_vac_merge['First Dose']

covid_summary= cov_vac_merge.groupby('State')[['Vaccinated','First Dose','Second Dose','Partially Vaccinated','% Partially Vaccinated']].sum().sort_values('Partially Vaccinated' ,ascending=False)
```

In the second line of the code where I try to divide Second Dose by First Dose, I do not get the right results. Below an example of the output I get:

```
State Vaccinated  First Dose     Second Dose     Partially Vaccinated   % Partially Vaccinated
  UK     5606041     5870786      5606041                264745                 527.854055
```

Instead of getting 527.85 for % Partially Vaccinated I should get 5606041/5870786 = **0.95**. Anyone knows what am I doing wrong in the division part of my code ?

Comment: what you posted there, is that a covid_summary? if so, then the % is a sum from the groupby

Comment: try to check on your `cov_vac_merge` again. I think you have already got the answer. But just like @Naveed said, you are doing summation in the groupby dataframe, which also sum up the percentage, that's why your answer is not what you have expected.

Comment: Just to add to @KevinChoonLiangYew 's answer: in order to get 0.95 you need to take an average for the percent.

Comment: Hi @Naveed, thanks for your answer. what do you mean by covid_summary ? I created a new DF to groupby my data. Not sure to understand the % is a sum from the groupby (still a newbie in Python)

Comment: thanks @KevinChoonLiangYew any idea and how I can remove the sum in the groupby and still get the results I want. I am tryin different routes but not sure how to approach. I have been mainly leveraging from the theory code.

Comment: Thanks @Yury but not sure how to approach this.

Comment: @Dim24, covid_summary is the df to which your groupby result is assigned

Comment: @Naveed I got it so the issue is the sum I applying in the groupby. But I still want the sum for all columns except % Partially vaccinated column. I need the division with the result I showed but I am not sure how to go about that. any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code should be something like this:

```py
covid_summary = cov_vac_merge.groupby('State').agg({
    'Vaccinated': np.sum,
    'First Dose': np.sum,
    'Second Dose': np.sum,
    'Partially Vaccinated': np.sum,
    '% Partially Vaccinated' : np.mean,  
})
```

For details about the grouping and aggregation in pandas, I recommend to read [this official article](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html).

Comment: Thank you very much @Yuri. I actually found a way and it worked with the following code:

cov_vac_merge['Partially Vaccinated'] = cov_vac_merge['First Dose'] - cov_vac_merge['Second Dose']



covid_summary= cov_vac_merge.groupb('State')[['Vaccinated','First Dose','Second Dose', 'Partially Vaccinated']].sum().sort_values('Partially Vaccinated',ascending=False)


covid_summary['% Partially Vaccinated'] = covid_summary['Second Dose'] / covid_summary['First Dose']